# Can't get jquery-masonry to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div class="item">
  <p>AAAAAAAAA amet tail frankfurter brisket, meatloaf beef ribs doner pork prosciutto ball tip rump tenderloin tongue. Pastrami fatback beef, sausage beef ribs venison tenderloin swine. Fatback leberkas kielbasa drumstick pork venison beef frankfurter. Turducken rump capicola, spare ribs leberkas brisket pork belly ball tip ground round. Tongue strip steak beef ribs shoulder.</p>
  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet tail frankfurter brisket, meatloaf beef ribs doner pork prosciutto ball tip rump tenderloin tongue. Pastrami fatback beef, sausage beef ribs venison tenderloin swine. Fatback leberkas kielbasa drumstick pork venison beef frankfurter. Turducken rump capicola, spare ribs leberkas brisket pork belly ball tip ground round. Tongue strip steak beef ribs shoulder.</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <p>BBBBBBBBmet tail frankfurter brisket, meatloaf beef ribs doner pork prosciutto ball tip rump tenderloin tongue. Pastrami fatback beef, sausage beef ribs venison tenderloin swine. Fatback leberkas kielbasa drumstick pork venison beef frankfurter. Turducken rump capicola, spare ribs leberkas brisket pork belly ball tip ground round. Tongue strip steak beef ribs shoulder.</p>
  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet tail frankfurter brisket, meatloaf beef ribs doner pork prosciutto ball tip rump tenderloin tongue. Pastrami fatback beef, sausage beef ribs venison tenderloin swine. Fatback leberkas kielbasa drumstick pork venison beef frankfurter. Turducken rump capicola, spare ribs leberkas brisket pork belly ball tip ground round. Tongue strip steak beef ribs shoulder.</p>
  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet tail frankfurter brisket, meatloaf beef ribs doner pork prosciutto ball tip rump tenderloin tongue. Pastrami fatback beef, sausage beef ribs venison tenderloin swine. Fatback leberkas kielbasa drumstick pork venison beef frankfurter. Turducken rump capicola, spare ribs leberkas brisket pork belly ball tip ground round. Tongue strip steak beef ribs shoulder.</p>
  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet tail frankfurter brisket, meatloaf beef ribs doner pork prosciutto ball tip rump tenderloin tongue. Pastrami fatback beef, sausage beef ribs venison tenderloin swine. Fatback leberkas kielbasa drumstick pork venison beef frankfurter. Turducken rump capicola, spare ribs leberkas brisket pork belly ball tip ground round. Tongue strip steak beef ribs shoulder.</p><p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet tail frankfurter brisket, meatloaf beef ribs doner pork prosciutto ball tip rump tenderloin tongue. Pastrami fatback beef, sausage beef ribs venison tenderloin swine. Fatback leberkas kielbasa drumstick pork venison beef frankfurter. Turducken rump capicola, spare ribs leberkas brisket pork belly ball tip ground round. Tongue strip steak beef ribs shoulder.</p>
  </div>

etc....
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}

.container{ width:940px; margin:0px auto;}

.item {
  width: 220px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I even pasted the default masontry code into my editor (http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/LDEGk/) and it was messing up.

http://jsfiddle.net/ntzMr/

These are my script files located in the body tag (the .js file is located in the root folder):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is throwing an exception `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'masonry' `

Comment: After inclusion of the `masonry` javascript it is working fine `http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ntzMr/1/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your inclusion of **masonry** library has some problem, After adding the external resource for masonry library your code is working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ntzMr/1/).

```
<script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think so, try with the resource file from masonry site

Comment: Yeah I grabbed jquery.masonry.min.js from the site and it's in the root along with the html and css file